# Flutter ListView not scrolling (I feel like I've tried every solution on the internet)

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, mobile

If I drag and hold my finger down I can see a few items that are below the cutoff of the screen but as soon as I let go, it just bounces back to the top. I tried using SingleChildScrollView places, tried setting primary = true, and a bunch of other stuff that didn't help. I'm fairly new to flutter so any help would be appreciated!! Let me know if any more info is needed.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:drink_specials/models/restaurant.dart';
import 'package:drink_specials/screens/home/restaurant_list.dart';

class RestaurantNameTextStyle {
  static TextStyle display5(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.copyWith(color: Colors.white);
  }
}

class RestaurantTypeTextStyle {
  static TextStyle display5(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(color: Colors.white);
  }
}


class RestaurantDetail extends StatelessWidget {

  final Restaurant restaurant;
  RestaurantDetail({Key key, @required this.restaurant}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final topContentText = Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 100.0),
        Text(
          restaurant.name,
          style: RestaurantNameTextStyle.display5(context),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  restaurant.restaurant_type,
                  style: RestaurantTypeTextStyle.display5(context),
                ))),
      ],
    );

    final topContent = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(restaurant.photo),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            )),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, .9)),
          child: Center(
            child: topContentText,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 8.0,
          top: 60.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );


    final bottomContent = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
          itemCount: restaurant.specials.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = restaurant.specials[index];
            return Card(
              elevation: 8.0,
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0)),
                child: ListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:20, vertical:10),
                  title: Text(item, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            )
                ),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          topContent,
          Expanded(
            child: bottomContent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code block to the functional code

Answer (score 5):

There is a `ListView` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` and both of them are scrollable. Scrolling on one of them should be disabled.

Comment: I thought that primary=false on the ListView would disable scrolling... I see that was not the case now. Thanks for your help, I feel dumb :)

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` already have scroll behavior so you won't need some `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to ListView solved the issue

`physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Answer (score 0):

As they already explained. If you have a **ListView.builder**, you don't need **SingleChildScrollView**.
Try removing SingleChildScrollView. The code should look like this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        topContent,
        Expanded(
            child: bottomContent,
        ),
      ],
  ),
);
```